# Matplotlib errorbar extra space at top and bottom

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I run the following lines, I get a plot with a large space at the top and the bottom with no bars.
How can I remove this extra space?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 1), columns=["parameter"])
df["standard_error"]= ((df.parameter**2)**0.5)/2
name = "plot"
x = ["A"+str(x) for x in df.index.tolist()]
y1 = df.parameter
yerr1 = df.standard_error
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(len(x))
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=22)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
trans1 = Affine2D().translate(-0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData
trans2 = Affine2D().translate(+0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData
er1 = ax.errorbar(y1, x, xerr=yerr1, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans1)
ax.axvline(x=0, color="black")
plt.savefig(name + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: `ax.margins(y=0.3)` ? See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html

Comment: ax.margins(y=0.01) works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the extra space below and above your smallest and largest data points along the y-axis then you can simply use [`plt.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html), e.g:

```
plt.ylim(0, 50)
```

Which will change the extent of the y-axis to the range 0 - 50. Similarly for the x-axis there's [`plt.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

Comment: ahh never mind, it also works with non numeric y-values. Should have tried it first

Comment: Internally the labels are numbered 0, 1, ..... So setting `ax.set_ylim(-0.1, len(labels)-1+0.1)` would set a padding of one tenth of the distance between two labels.